# Replay Status is failing during LoadRunner scripting

Tags: jsp, performance-testing, loadrunner

During replaying the recorded scripts in LoadRunner 12.5, I am facing the following mentioned error :
SignIN.c(38): web_submit_data("Dashboard.jsp") started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
SignIN.c(38): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://****************.jsp"      [MsgId: MERR-26612]
SignIN.c(38): web_submit_data("Dashboard.jsp") highest severity level was "ERROR", 1109 body bytes, 251 header bytes, 30 chunking overhead bytes    [MsgId: MMSG-26387]
SignIN.c(38): Notify: Transaction "T02_Sign IN" ended with a "Fail" status (Duration: 7.5173 Wasted Time: 0.2405).
SignIN.c(38): Notify: Transaction "T02_Sign IN" has 1 error message(s).
SignIN.c(38): Notify: The 1st error message associated with transaction "T02_Sign IN" is "Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://**************.jsp""

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You have unhandled dynamic data

b) You have continue on error turned on & you are not explicitly checking for a positive expected result on each page and then branching your code when the positive expected result does not appear (root cause of 500, greater than 90% of time in script development )

c) Combination of A) and B)

Answer (score 1):

Did you make any correlations? Usually similar errors appear when application need some dynamic data (for example user session id or CSRF token etc). Try to record script one more time and compare two recorded versions.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the request and compare it with the original recorded request.

a) check dynamic values and use correlations accordingly

b) cross check headers in the request

Still if it won't work, check application manually could be server is down  :)